# Hue supervisor startup error - $HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Tags: mysql, apache, hadoop, hive, hue

I have installed hadoop, all services working well. similarly hue installed as per instruction and configured properly (similarly hive). Everything i have checked many times its good. But when i try to start hue(supervisor) i got this error. Please suggest what should i do to solve this.

```
root@slave3:/usr/local/master/hue/build/env# bin/supervisor
$HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/master/hadoop
$HIVE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf
$HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
find: `/usr/lib/hive/lib': No such file or directory
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=
$HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf:/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../..   /../../desktop/conf:/usr/local/master/hadoop/conf
CWD=/usr/local/master/hue/build/env
Executing /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../java-lib/BeeswaxServer.jar --beeswax 8002 --desktop-host 127.0.0.1 --desktop-port 8802 --query-lifetime 604800000 --metastore 8003
(30362) *** Controller starting at Tue Mar  4 23:46:57 2014
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 ... 3 more
Should start 1 new children
Controller.spawn_children(number=1)
$HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/master/hadoop
$HIVE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf
$HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
find: `/usr/lib/hive/lib': No such file or directory
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=
$HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf:/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../../../desktop/conf:/usr/local/master/hadoop/conf
CWD=/usr/local/master/hue/build/env
Executing /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../java-lib/BeeswaxServer.jar --beeswax 8002 --desktop-host 127.0.0.1 --desktop-port 8802 --query-lifetime 604800000 --metastore 8003
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 ... 3 more
$HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/master/hadoop
$HIVE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf
$HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
find: `/usr/lib/hive/lib': No such file or directory
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=
$HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf:/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../../../desktop/conf:/usr/local/master/hadoop/conf
CWD=/usr/local/master/hue/build/env
Executing /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../java-lib/BeeswaxServer.jar --beeswax 8002 --desktop-host 127.0.0.1 --desktop-port 8802 --query-lifetime 604800000 --metastore 8003
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
  ... 3 more
$HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/master/hadoop
$HIVE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf
$HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
find: `/usr/lib/hive/lib': No such file or directory
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=
$HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf:/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../../../desktop/conf:/usr/local/master/hadoop/conf
CWD=/usr/local/master/hue/build/env
Executing /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../java-lib/BeeswaxServer.jar --beeswax 8002 --desktop-host 127.0.0.1     --desktop-port 8802 --query-lifetime 604800000 --metastore 8003
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:190)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 ... 3 more
(30417) *** Child exiting
(30362) *** Controller exiting
```

I have installed python, mysql also. In mysql i have created a database hadoop.       Everything i did as per my previous hue installation exp. Thats working fine. But this installation giving problems.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing to this:

```
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
find: `/usr/lib/hive/lib': No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure that your $HIVE_HOME is invalid... Maybe something in /usr/local/master/hue ?

Comment: Indeed, here is the list of env variables: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/branch-2.5/apps/beeswax/beeswax_server.sh#L41